# Infinite loop of http requests in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I saw other questions about this but didn't helped me.

I have function in angularjs controller:

```
$scope.getUser = function(id){
    ret = null;
    $http.get('services/rest/users/' + id).then(
        function(response){
            ret = response.data.name;
        }, 
        function(response){
        }
    )
        return ret;
}
```

And I call that function in html:

```
<div ng-repeat = "move in moves">Player:<span> {{getUser(move.player_id)}} </span> - {{move.guess}} - {{move.answer}}</div>
```

And this creates infinite loop of `'services/rest/users/' + id` requests. I saw that angular can do this when some object in scope is always changing, but I don't see this here.

Comment: Isn't it due to digest cycle getting called again and again whenever your one request (backend) is getting completed? That can call ng-repeat directive again.

Comment: First, make get user a promise using $q and resolve if response or reject if error. Second, it is a bad practice to call multiple http requests in ng-repeat. Bring your data in one request if you can and when the data is ready, populate an array binded to the moves scope variable.

Comment: It loops even without `ng-repeat`. I called that function from another place and it started looping again. Will try with `$q`.

Comment: Never use functions in view that make asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach is all wrong.

`$http` is asynchronous and `ret` will always be null when returned from `getUser()`

Never use functions in view that directly make asynchronous requests.

Instead, in controller( or better yet in service) iterate all your `moves` , request player data , and add that as property of each `move`

```
function getUser(id) {
  return $http.get('services/rest/users/' + id).then(function(response) {
    return response.data.name;
  }).catch(function() {
    return 'Unknown Player';
  })
}


angular.forEach($scope.moves, function(move){
   getUser(move.player_id).then(function(player){
      move.player = player;
   });
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat = "move in moves">Player:<span> {{move.player)}} </span>...</div>
```